# Why xhtml1-strict.dtd give extra space?

Tags: html, css

The difference between [table-default.html](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/467352/Screenshots/table-default.html) and [table-dtd.html](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/467352/Screenshots/table-dtd.html) is an extra line:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```

in front of the following code:

```
  <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="960">
    <tbody><tr>
      <td bgcolor="#00ff00">Up</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody></table>

  <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="960">
    <tbody><tr>
      <td bgcolor="#3f3f3f"><img src="http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/467352/Screenshots/line.jpg" height="5" width="960"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>  

  <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="960">
    <tbody><tr>
      <td bgcolor="#0000ff">Down</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody></table>
```

How can I remove the extra space (above and below the red line image) in `table-dtd.html` by using `css`?

Comment: I would recommend writing this as one table, instead of three. Besides that, I don't think there is any reason to use a table here anyway.

Comment: @Sumurai8 I guess this is just a minimum example to show the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the first file is rendered in quirks mode, block elements like `td` will collapse around inline elements. In standards mode (with the doctype) they will not. The latter is the standard behaviour; it's more consistent with how other elements work.

The solution is to use `display:block` on the image, so it's no longer an inline element.

In the `<head>`:

```
<style type="text/css">
  td img {display:block}
</style>
```

But if that's how all the HTML looks like, it will need a *lot* more work to iron out all quirks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `float: left` for your image:

```
<img style="float: left" ... >
```

`display: block` works as well (maybe more elegant):

```
<img style="display: block" ... >
```

Comment: Aw... seems I typed too slowly. I started typing my answer before there was any mention of `display:block` here!